# Is there a way to send SMS from Server?

Tags: mysql, mobile, sms

There is a way to send SMS from private online server?
Or another way to transfer text from server to a mobile phone?
Thank you.

Comment: "*There is a way to send SMS from private online server?*" - Yes, [there is](https://www.google.com/search?sms+gateway). "*Or another way to transfer text from server to a mobile phone*?" - What, like email/HTTP/instant messaging?

Comment: There are many services online to send SMS message using your server (simple search in google give you several). One of them is voipcheap (https://www.voipcheap.com/).

Comment: eggyal - What do you mean "SMS getaway"?
Miguel - I couldn't find the SMS service in Voipcheap. Can you tell me what to search in Google to find those?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway

Answer (score 0):

You can pay a service or depending upon the carrier of the target phone there are various ways.  Here is the cheap way, simply send an email.  The carrier will create a text message:

Alltel
[10-digit phone number]@message.alltel.com
Example: 1234567890@message.alltel.com

AT&T (formerly Cingular)
[10-digit phone number]@txt.att.net
[10-digit phone number]@mms.att.net (MMS)
[10-digit phone number]@cingularme.com
Example: 1234567890@txt.att.net

Nextel (now Sprint Nextel)
[10-digit telephone number]@messaging.nextel.com
Example: 1234567890@messaging.nextel.com

Sprint PCS (now Sprint Nextel)
[10-digit phone number]@messaging.sprintpcs.com
[10-digit phone number]@pm.sprint.com (MMS)
Example: 1234567890@messaging.sprintpcs.com

T-Mobile
[10-digit phone number]@tmomail.net
Example: 1234567890@tmomail.net

US Cellular
[10-digit phone number]email.uscc.net (SMS)
[10-digit phone number]@mms.uscc.net (MMS)
Example: 1234567890@email.uscc.net

Verizon
[10-digit phone number]@vtext.com
[10-digit phone number]@vzwpix.com (MMS)
Example: 1234567890@vtext.com

Virgin Mobile USA
[10-digit phone number]@vmobl.com
Example: 1234567890@vmobl.com

Comment: Is there a chance you have list of those mails for Israeli carriers?

Comment: you should be able to go to their site or call and ask.